# output XML to dataset

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization, dataset

I've been trying to read an xml file from an external source to get it into a dataset.  I've taken the schema and compiled my class through xsd and have loaded it into the solution.

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<CAMDealerManifest AssetURL="http://www.the placewherethefilelives.com/CAMPublic/d98c8185/" DealerCode="41065" DealerGuid="bc0d0bc8-b37b-11e3-a345-ac162dbc18f8" DealerName="Ron Hibbard Toyota" ManifestId="13" ManifestURL="http://www.toyota.com/CAMPublic/d/41065-bc0d0bc8.xml" Path="41065-bc0d0bc8" ProviderId="1011" WebsiteVendorName="WorldDealer">
  <CAMCampaigns count="15" dateTime="2014-09-16T17:18:40.877-07:00">
    <CAMCampaign ManifestId="13" endDate="2014-12-31T11:59:59-08:00" flightDates="08/01/14 - 12/31/14" geography="National" groupName="National" id="68" name="National - Corolla Style Elevated" priority="0" required="false" startDate="2014-08-01T12:00:00-07:00">
      <CAMCreative SubGroup="Corolla Style Elevated" Id="49" Name="National - Corolla Style Elevated" ImageAltText="Toyota's national banner for the stylish 2014 Corolla" ImageSearchTerms="Toyota, 2014 Corolla, Style Elevated, New Heights" Link="New Inventory" Model="Corolla" MonthYear="08-2014" Priority="3" Required="false">
        <CAMCreativeSource CAMAssetCount="1" Height="409" Width="990" MediaBinAssetId="0E1C886A-C5CE-4409-AD36-7070D614A7A6" MediaBinFileName="03-14_01_2014_nat-style-elevated_990x409_0000000460_corolla_o_xta.jpg">
          <CAMAsset Path="National/Corolla-Style-Elevated/National---Corolla-Style-Elevated/990/409/" Id="1273" Name="08-14_01_National-Corolla-Style-Elevated_990x409_431_Corolla_O_xta.jpg" Height="409" Width="990" assetType="JPG" Guid="b9f4d3cd-fefd-4ff3-b209-338f409e551c" Md5Hex="3e328dc32a2db9fc1f3d6a2167d3e5d2">
            <CAMTracking>
              <SiteCatalyst version="1.0">
                <Click tmsomni.events="event28" tmsomni.products=";08-14_01_National-Corolla-Style-Elevated_990x409_431_Corolla_O_xta;;;event28=1"/>
                <Impression tmsomni.events="event29" tmsomni.products=";08-14_01_National-Corolla-Style-Elevated_990x409_431_Corolla_O_xta;;event29=1;evar43=img|evar61=corolla|evar54=o|evar49={$CAM_PAGE_POSITION}"/>
              </SiteCatalyst>
            </CAMTracking>
          </CAMAsset>
        </CAMCreativeSource>
      </CAMCreative>
  </CAMCampaign>
</CAMCampaigns>
<CAMExpiredCampaigns count="0" dateTime="2014-09-16T17:18:40.873-07:00"/>
</CAMDealerManifest>
```

I can't seem to get this xml to list or put into a dataset.  I'm new to deserializing xml and could use some assistance.

Comment: Use the [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx) method of the `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call ReadXml with the path to the file:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(string PathToFile);
```

Works pretty well; will even create all the relations (notice `CAMDealerManifestId` in the screenshot).

[image: Tables created from DataSet.ReadXml]

Your file went in with only a modification to the XML declaration -- had to change `standalone` value from `true` to `yes`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

If you're reading this in as a string, you could do something like this:

```
var xmlString = HoweverYouGetTheString().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
xmlString[0] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";

using (var reader = new System.IO.StringReader(String.Join("\r\n", xmlString)))
{
    dataSet.ReadXml(reader);
}
```

Comment: The file will be sitting on a remote I'll be pulling down. I ran the `DataSet.ReadXml(string fileName)` with  the xml as is.  it errored. Did I miss something?

Comment: I had an issue with the XML declaration (bottom of answer) -- is that the issue? Otherwise, what is the exception?

Comment: I've been having no luck getting a dataset to display. I'm pulling this from an external source.  How did you get the xml to display?

Comment: Are you getting the XML as a string, then?

Comment: Yes I am.  I have converted my schemas to classes as well.

Comment: Do you want this as a `DataSet` or as objects?

Comment: I'd think a dataset.  What Im trying to do is call a remote xml file into a dataset and insert it into a table.   I tried directly from sql bur doesnt allow  remote access like that withought going into ssis.